# format string to specific format including dots and dashes

Tags: r, arrays, string, char

I have a string with numbers only and it always has the same witdh. I need this string in a specific format.

```
original = "00000000000000"
outcome = "00.000.000/0000-00"
```

Is there a way simple way to do this? Could it be applied to a vector of strings?

Comment: This is unclear. Is this a number? Does it always have this width?

Comment: it is not a number, since it is defined with ```" "```. And yes, it always has this width. I edited my question to include that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the width is constant, we can use `sub`:

```r
original = "00000000000000"
sub("(.{2})(.{3})(.{3})(.{4})(.{2})", "\\1.\\2.\\3/\\4-\\5", original)
# [1] "00.000.000/0000-00"
```